# Twig: Update template data from ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twig

1: index.html

```
<!-- begin filter -->
<input type="radio" id="" name="top10" value="top10">Top 10
<input type="radio" id="" name="top20" value="top20">Top 20
<input type="radio" id="" checked="checked" name="all" value="all">All
<!-- end filters -->

{% for user in users %}
    {% include 'userslist.html' %}      
{% endfor %}
```

---

In the 'index.html' the default action is list all users. When I change the filter, this call a ajax function in 'user.js'.

2: user.js

```
$.ajax({


                        url: 'user/find/'+params,
                        type: 'get',
                        data: null,
                        async: false,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(dataJson){
                            ?????
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){},
                        complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){}
                    });

                    return jsonContratos;
                }
```

---

This ajax function call the class User.php

3: User.php

```
class User extends AppRequest
{      

      public function __construct(){}

      public function index_action()
      {
        $this->template('index.html', Array('users' => $this->find()));
      }

      public function find()
      {
        $arrayUsers = dataBase->findUsersByFilters($_GET['params']);

        if( $this->isAjaxRequest() ){

           $array = Array('users' => $arrayUsers)

           $this->template('index.html', $array);
        }else{
          return $arrayUsers;
        }

      }
}
```

---

Questions: 
-How can I send the new users list to the template, using the ajax callback?
-Or what the best way to do this?
-Is possible to do this with Json?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow! First remark: `async: false` -> no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, don't use `async: false`. AJAX is - by definition - asynchronous. Concerning your question: simply update your view in the success callback. You return HTML so simply inject it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'user/find/'+params,
    type: 'get',
    data: null,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // for example
        $("#some-id-or-class-of-your-main-element").html(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){},
    complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus ){}
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with json? I have twig template, each offer on page consists of more than 100 line of html code formated, with spaceless is nearly zero for one. But if i want to display 15 of these offers, this is pretty huge html response. So i am asking if is the some possible way, to process twig template with JS and json data. Thank you

Comment: @ErikKubica Of course it may be possible, but you'd better post a new question…

Comment: I cant, stacko. is blocking me to add new questions :-( ... I am experimenting with javascript template, (not hard-coding html into js, but create html with js) then loop through the json data :-)  snippet here http://pastebin.com/ft7iZEx7 if my code helped to someone please click on "This comment helped..."